# Can you lock notepad files?

Tags: batch-file, notepad++, notepad

I am currently working on a little (quite bad) batch file password protected folder. To increase the security of my password and files what can I do to somehow make the file "un-viewable" to others?

Comment: Have a a read here for information on password protecting files on Windows: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000705.htm

Answer (score 1):

```
@Echo Off

rem To *store* the password, use this:
echo thePassword> "%~F0:.dat"

rem To *read* the password, use this:
set /P pass=< "%~F0:.dat"
echo Password: "%pass%"
```

This way, the file where the password is stored is "un-viewable" to anyone that don't know this trick!

Comment: You should mention that you are using NTFS Alternate Data Streams, which are only available on NTFS volumes.